# gradle: how to write a groovy task

Tags: gradle, groovy

I've been trying to work through the [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html).  This seems like an incredibly simple thing I want to do, but I just can't figure out how to make it work.

I want to write an external groovy file to define a task, then call that task in `build.gradle`. Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
// Apply the groovy plugin to add support for Groovy
apply plugin: 'groovy'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // We use the latest groovy 2.x version for building this library
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7'
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()    
    // We use the awesome Spock testing and specification framework
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task myTask (type: my.package.MyTask)
```

Then, under `src/main/groovy/my/package` I have `MyTask.groovy`:

```
package my.package

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction

class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    String greeting = 'hello from MyTask'

    @TaskAction
    def greet(){
        println greeting
    }
}
```

I can't even list the tasks:

```
$ gradle tasks

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/projects/gradle/build.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle'.
> Could not get unknown property 'my' for root project 'gradle' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.193 secs
```

At this point, I have absolutely no idea what's going on or how to do what I want.  This seems like the most simple possible example but following the user guide has gotten me nowhere.  No matter what I do, I can't get past that exception.

How do I write a groovy file and use that to define a new task in the build file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place your groovy files under:

```
rootProjectDir/buildSrc/src/main/groovy
```

Reference:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#N14573

**EDIT**

I never tried changing the location of `buildSrc` but it appears to be an unresolved issue:
https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2816

(correct it if I'm wrong)

Comment: ok I got to a new error now, so thanks.  Sidenote though: is there a way to change that? I'm trying to learn this so I can contribute to a larger project but the larger project doesn't have a buildSrc folder

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've got your src moved to buildSrc you'll also need to fix a small typo in MyTask.groovy:

Instead of

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.DefaultTask
```

use

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
```

That ought to fix your `@TaskAction` annotation.